# Argument of type 'RegistryGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I use NgRx.

Dispatching action is:

```
this.store.dispatch(RegistryActions.ToggleRegistryBlockAction(block));
```

Where block has type:

```
export interface RegistryGroup extends RegistryGeneric {
  open: boolean;
}
```

Action:

```
export const ToggleRegistryBlockAction = createAction(
  "[ToggleRegistryBlockOpen] - Toggle Registry",
  props<{ block: RegistryGroup }>()
);
```

Why do I get this error on the line `this.store.dispatch(RegistryActions.ToggleRegistryBlockAction(block));`:

```
Argument of type 'RegistryGroup' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ block: RegistryGroup; }'.
  Property 'block' is missing in type 'RegistryGroup' but required in type '{ block: RegistryGroup; }'.ts(2345)
registry.actions.ts(47, 11): 'block' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by defining action params like this `props<{ block: RegistryGroup }>()` you expect that you will pass `{block: someGroup}` object, not just `someGroup`. to fix it just wrap it in object parenthes

```
this.store.dispatch(RegistryActions.ToggleRegistryBlockAction({block}));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Or I can chnage action on this notation: `export const ToggleRegistryBlockAction = createAction(
  "[ToggleRegistryBlockOpen] - Toggle Registry",
  props<RegistryGroup>()
);`

Comment: Could you help me, why do I get this message: `Cannot add property open, object is not extensible`

Comment: In this code:

`on(
    RegistryActions.ToggleRegistryBlockAction,
    (state: RegistryState, block: RegistryGroup) => {
      debugger;
      return {
        ...state,
        Registry: state.Registry.map((reg) => {
          if (reg.Id == block.Id) reg.open = true;
          return reg;
        }),
      };
    }
  ),`

Comment: On the line: `if (reg.Id == block.Id) reg.open = true;`

Comment: try this: `return {...state, Registry: state.Registry.map(reg => reg.Id == block.Id ? {...reg, open: true} : reg)}`. your code mutates an object, while my example creates the new one

Comment: This works unstable, it breask Chrome browser

Comment: is RegistryGroup a class, not just a simple js object?

Comment: it is an interface. how it breaks then ?

Comment: It is interface, right. Initially this object has no property open. When data comes from server. Then after click I want to set this property as true/false

Comment: what do you mean by saying "it works unstable" ? is there any error in the console or what?

Comment: Chrome is freezed after I dispatched this action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228790/discussion-between-andrei-and-irina).